# Hibernate doesn't map javax.persistence.Entity classes

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I've been trying to get `@Entity` to work so hibernate can recognize it, but i'm actually getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped[from User u where u.username = ? and u.password = ? ]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java: 96)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java: 120)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java: 234)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java: 158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan. < init > (HQLQueryPlan.java: 126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan. < init > (HQLQueryPlan.java: 88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java: 167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java: 301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java: 236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java: 1800)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java: 342)
  ...71 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java: 189)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java: 109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java: 95)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java: 332)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java: 3678)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java: 3567)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java: 708)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java: 564)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java: 301)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java: 249)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java: 278)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java: 206)
  ...79 more
```

Here is my model, I used `@Entity` from `javax.persistence`, it used to be working when i used the hibernate annotation, but no the mapped classes map is empty.

```
package com.itworx.eshop.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String password;

    private String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

and my hibernate configuration is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.itworx.eshop.integration"/>
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/db.properties" />

     <bean id="eshopDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/spring/eshop-persistence.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="eshopDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="eshopPersistence" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.itworx.eshop.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean> 

 <!--    <bean id="eshopSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="eshopDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.itworx.eshop.model"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>  -->

    <bean id="eshopTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="eshopDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="eshopTransactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

And here is persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="eshopPersistence">
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: @Table name should be User?

Comment: For starters you are using the wrong transaction manager, use the `JpaTransactionManager` instead. Also make sure that you are scanning the proper package with your `packagesToScan` property. Add your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Another note your `<context:annotation-config />` is unnecessary as that is already implied with `<context:component-scan />`.

Comment: Table name is actually users in the database

Comment: i have already a persistence.xml file, what's wrong with the transaction manager I'm currently using?

Comment: Is your Entity class in package `com.itworx.eshop.model`?

Comment: @MuhammadAllam        He meant that you should add your persistence.xml file in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes it's, it used to be working with hibernat's @Entity annotation.

Comment: I did add persistence.xml now

Comment: Thanks, I will take care of this later :)

Comment: The tx manager isn't for JPA but for plain JDBC it will not work for JPA. `@NamedQuery` is a hibernate annotation not a JPA one. How are you obtaining the `EntityManager`? Which makes me suspect the same for the `@Table` annotation.

Comment: @M. Deimum `javax.persistence.NamedQuery` was generated using eclipse generate JPA from table, i'm obtaining the entity manager this way:
`@PersistenceContext(unitName="eshopPersistence")
private EntityManager entityManager;`